Issues Fetching Unread Emails from IMAP Server
I am using MicroPython on an ESP8266 to connect to an IMAP server and fetch unread emails. Although I can connect to the server and log in successfully, I’m having trouble detecting new unread emails. The email fetching functionality isn’t working as expected. I am working in micropython 1.22.2 because this is the latest version that I found has ussl.
import network
import usocket as socket
import ussl as ssl
import utime as time

SSID = "wifi"
WIFI_PASSWORD = "pass"

EMAIL = "ex@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "APP password"

IMAP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
IMAP_PORT = 993 

# Connect to Wi-Fi
def connect_wifi(ssid, password, timeout=30):
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    start_time = time.time()
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            print("Failed to connect to Wi-Fi.")
            return False
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Connected to Wi-Fi:", wlan.ifconfig())
    return True

def connect_to_imap():
    try:
        addr = socket.getaddrinfo(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)[0][-1]
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(10)
        s.connect(addr)
        s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
        print("IMAP connected and SSL wrapped.")
        return s
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"IMAP connection error: {e}")
        return None

def send_command(s, command):
    print(f"Sending command: {command.decode()}")
    s.write(command + b'\r\n')
    response = b""
    while True:
        try:
            part = s.read(1024)
            if not part:
                break
            response += part
            if b'OK' in part or b'NO' in part or b'BAD' in part:
                break
        except OSError as e:
            print(f"Socket read error: {e}")
            break
    response_str = response.decode()
    print(f"Response: {response_str}")
    return response_str

def login_imap(s):
    login_cmd = f'A1 LOGIN "{EMAIL}" "{PASSWORD}"'.encode()
    response = send_command(s, login_cmd)
    return 'OK' in response

def fetch_unread_emails(s):
    print("Selecting INBOX...")
    send_command(s, b'A2 SELECT INBOX')
    
    print("Searching for unseen emails...")
    search_cmd = b'A3 SEARCH UNSEEN'
    search_response = send_command(s, search_cmd)
    
    parts = search_response.split()
    email_ids = [part for part in parts if part.isdigit()]
    
    if email_ids:
        print(f"Found email IDs: {email_ids}")
        for email_id in email_ids:
            fetch_cmd = f'A4 FETCH {email_id} BODY[TEXT]'.encode()
            email_response = send_command(s, fetch_cmd)
            print(f"Email ID {email_id} content: {email_response}")
    else:
        print("No new emails.")

def main():
    if connect_wifi(SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD):
        while True:
            s = connect_to_imap()
            if s:
                if login_imap(s):
                    fetch_unread_emails(s)
                s.close()
            time.sleep(15)

main()


I have tested the script with different buffer sizes and made sure that the connection to the server is successful.

Is the Found email IDs: message displayed, and if so, does it contain the expected content?

'Found email IDs:' is not displayed. The response is: No new emails.

What is search_response set to when send_command() returns? Also are you aware that the ESP8266 has only 80KB of RAM, and significantly less than that is available when you're running MicroPython. It's quite possible your CPU doesn't have the memory available to store downloaded messages.

Are you sure that message ids are always strictly numeric?

@romkey The response I am getting is a list of UIDs like 123 124 125, which correspond to the unread emails. Is that what you're asking about ? I am aware the ESP8266 has only 80kb of ram, but since the emails I'm dealing with are very short, I don't think memory is the issue

While your buffering is kind of broken (and will break if I put OK or NO in a message), have you tried printing out everything you get?  Did the select succeed?  Are you sure there is UNSEEN email?  Writing yourself a protocol log will help answer a lot of questions.
